# passing array of objects to a component in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am having problem to pass an array of objects to component in Vue.js 2.2.

Here is my component

```
<vue-grid :fields = "[
  {name: 'Person Name', isSortable: true}, 
  {name: 'Country', isSortable: true}]"
></vue-grid>
```

It doesn't work as it renders the curly braces in the browser.
I've tried without the quotation `"` in the object and without the colon `:` in front of `fields` property. None of these work either.
However, if I just pass a simple string that works. I don't know why object is not working.
I have found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577211/passing-an-array-to-a-component-in-vue-js-2-0) but answer was given for php. I need the solution just for JavaScript. I want to hard code the object array in the component.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are passing it correctly.  You must have something else happening behind the scenes. Ensure your template has a wrapping element.  [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqo5cjpc/4/)

```
<div id="vue-app">
    <h2>
        Vue App
    </h2>
    <vue-grid :fields = "[
        {name: 'Person Name', isSortable: true}, 
        {name: 'Country', isSortable: true}]"
    ></vue-grid>
</div>
<script id="vue-grid-template" type="text/x-template">
    <div>
        <h3>Grid</h3>
        <div class="grid">
            Fields are:
            <ul>
                <li v-for="field in fields">
                    {{field.name}} - {{field.isSortable}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script>
    Vue.component('vue-grid', {
        props: ['fields'],
        template: '#vue-grid-template'
    });

    new Vue({
        el: '#vue-app'
    });
</script>
```